# SessionFactory Hibernate Error (Spring MVC project)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

This is the error:
Caused by:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of 
type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean 
which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

This is my `persistence-context.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Datasource to connection management (http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html)
     -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${datasource.mysql.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${datasource.mysql.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${datasource.mysql.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${datasource.mysql.password}" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${datasource.mysql.maxIdle}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="br.com.mirian.martins.core.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">${datasource.mysql.timeout}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
        scope="prototype">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        <property name="defaultTimeout" value="120" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

This is my `DAOImpl (generic)`:

```
/**
 * Classe generica com metodos padroes utilizados na camada de persistencia
 * 
 * @param <T>
 * @param <ID>
 */
public class DAOImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>{

    private transient final Class<T> clazz;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public DAOImpl() {
    this.clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) 
    getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    /**
     * SessionFactory injection
     * 
     * @param sessionFactory
     */
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Recupera a sessao corrente
     * 
     * @return sessao corrente
     */
    protected Session getSession() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    /**
     * Utiliza a sessao corrente para criar uma nova instancia de criteria
     * 
     * @return instancia de criteria
     */
    protected Criteria createCriteria() {
    return getSession().createCriteria(clazz);
    }

    /**
     * Utiliza a sessao corrente para criar uma nova query
     * 
     * @param hql
     * @return query
     */
    protected Query createQuery(String hql) {
    return getSession().createQuery(hql);
    }
}
```

This is my `controller`:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {


    return "index";

    }

}
```

Please, if someone now how to solve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: where's your spring configuration file? you should put TransactionManager in spring config file. So that, spring can enable Spring transaction for hibernate!

Comment: could you please add code of your web.xml and servlet-context.xml file

Comment: It is the root cause exception? Can you show full stacktrace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are getting confused in two things

1. **JPA EntityManagerFactory**

   `EntityManagerFactory` and `EntityManager`. They are defined by the JPA standard.
2. **SessionFactory**

   `SessionFactory` and `Session` are hibernate-specific.

both have there Pros & Cons, since you use `SessionFactory` (not JPA), you shouldn't use persistence.xml at all.

**JPA EntityManagerFactory**

If you want to use JPA with Spring, you need to put `persistence.xml` into `META-INF` folder inside your source folder, and declare `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory` in `applicationContext.xml`

```
<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name = "persistenceUnitName" value = "MyJPA" />
</bean>
```

Then you can inject `EntityManager` into your Spring bean using `@PersistenceContext`:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

**persistence.xml**

> this files usually contain details related to your database, such as
>   connection strings and their respective user names and passwords
>   including other ORM related information.  These details can be placed
>   in other locations so you need not explicitly have one, although
>   having such a file usually makes all persistence related information
>   available in one place which makes looking up certain settings and
>   configurations easier.

**SessionFactory**

If you want to use `SessionFactory` then you have to declare `sessionFactory` bean into your `applicationContext.xml` as follows

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${datasource.mysql.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${datasource.mysql.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${datasource.mysql.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${datasource.mysql.password}" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${datasource.mysql.maxIdle}" />
    </bean>

     <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.edgeowt.entities"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                  <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

Then you can able to inject `SessionFactory` into your spring bean using `@Autowired`

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

hope this will help you to solve your problem...

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `@Component` at the top of your DAO (or a similar Spring annotation).   Also do you have  `<context:annotation-config/>` and `<context:component-scan base-package="whatever"/>` in your web.xml?   You have to tell Spring to go out and sniff around for annotations.

Comment: We add `<context:annotation-config/>` and `<context:component-scan base-package="whatever"/>` in `Spring applicationContext.xml` file not int `web.xml`

Answer (score 1):

You must add `@Repository` (Spring annotation) at the top of your DAOImpl class. Moreover, you must insert `<context:component-scan base-package="packageName"/>` to scan all your project and find mvn components in your project and `<mvc:annotation-driven />` (to enable to use spring annotation) in spring configuration, so that it can understand your spring annotation.